# Docker Not Adding User To MariaDB With Dockerfile

Tags: docker, mariadb

So this is my Dockerfile,

```
FROM mariadb:10.3.5

RUN apt-get update & apt-get upgrade -y

ENV MYSQL_USER=user1 \
    MYSQL_USER_PASSWORD=pass5 \
    MYSQL_DATABASE=db \
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=XXX

ADD . /

WORKDIR /
```

However, this does not add my user1 to the database build. The root password works but that is it. I have completely removed all the pass tests i have done, including all volume data but still does not add the user. So what am I doing wrong?

Thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Official [mariadb docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb/) has built-in enviromental variables `MYSQL_USER` and `MYSQL_PASSWORD`:

> These variables are optional, used in conjunction to create a new user
>   and to set that user's password. This user will be granted superuser
>   permissions (see above) for the database specified by the
>   MYSQL_DATABASE variable. Both variables are required for a user to be
>   created.

So, the variable `MYSQL_PASSWORD` was misspelled (it was defined as `MYSQL_USER_PASSWORD`) and that's why mysql user was not created at all.

The correct `Dockerfile` is:

```
FROM mariadb:10.3.5

RUN apt-get update & apt-get upgrade -y

ENV MYSQL_USER=user1 \
    MYSQL_PASSWORD=pass5 \
    MYSQL_DATABASE=db \
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=XXX

ADD . /

WORKDIR /
```

Comment: I must have looked over those docs 100's of times and just completely missed that - thanks!